# Newton polynomial interpolation, which formula for the coefficients in rigth?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, newton-series

I'm studying Newton Polynomial interpolation, and there are formulas for the coefficients $c_i$ in the expansion

$$P(x) = c_0 + c_1(x-x_0) + c_2 (x-x_0)(x-x_1)$$

[On Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial#Application), the third coefficient is

$$\frac{\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}-\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}}{x_2-x_0}$$

[On here](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e176/lectures/ch7/node4.html), it is

$$\frac{\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_0)}{x_2-x_0}-\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}}{x_2-x_1}$$

which one is rigth?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}-\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}}{x_2-x_0}=\frac{\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_0)}{x_2-x_0}-\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}}{x_2-x_1}$$
Both are the same and if you want to check them,take  random numbers to see that they give you same the value

Answer (score 0):

The following version $$c_2= \frac{\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_0)}{x_2-x_0}-\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}}{x_2-x_1}$$ is correct.

You may verify it by evaluating the polynomial at $$x=x_0, x=x_1,   and,  x=x_2.$$

Comment: I indeed found it to be the one while doing my calculations. So Wikipedia is wrong... I've also found this: https://www.nptel.ac.in/courses/122104019/numerical-analysis/Rathish-kumar/rathish-oct31/fratnode5.html where it's also wrong. Thanks